# SuiteScript 2.0 Map Reduce Script Parameters

Tags: netsuite, software-design, suitescript2.0

I have written a map/reduce script to check a box on thousands of journal entry records. I have a dynamic parameter that passes in journal status when script is run. In suitescript 1.0 I grab script parameters off context object.

I'm sure it is similar in 2.0, but I can't seem to find it on context object in 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

import N/runtime

then

```
var me = runtime.getCurrentScript();
var paramVal = me.getParameter({name:'custscript_my_script_param'});
```

Comment: this works... needed the runtime module. thank you bknights.